# How Does This Style Photo Can be taken?

Tags: black-and-white

I wonder if anybody can explain to me how does this photo has taken and what is the name of this style photographing. Thanks in Advance
[image]

UPDATE : Please help me DSLR setting , too.
I have Canon EOS 700D (Rebel T5i)

Comment: When asking a question, you should be clear and specific about what you actually need to know. Check this on [how to ask a good question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Then it is clear for anyone who can answer and you can get the exact answers you need.

Comment: In particular, [this question on meta](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/677/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-how-do-i-achieve-this-effect-question) gives good guidance as to how to ask "effect" questions. Also note it's almost entirely about the lighting, very little at all to do with DSLR settings.

Comment: [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871)

Comment: @shahab  We can not tell you what sittings to use, you need to know how to assess the light in a scene and how to set your camera setting to photograph what you see. The first thing you need to do is get some good books ( or online books ) and learn the basics of photography and lighting ( photography is the art of capturing light; understanding how light behaves and how to capture it and use it is the key to taking great photos ) AND Volunteer to intern with pro photographer

Answer (score 5):

This "style" is called *black and white*.

Comment: And maybe slightly more specific - black and white portrait.

Comment: ...with a flash to make the background go black.

Answer (score 4):

The style very much reminds me of the Dutch painter [Johannes Vermeer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Vermeer)'s [*Girl with a Pearl Earring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girl_with_a_Pearl_Earring):

[image]

The head scarf and subject positioning are very similar. The lighting is very similar as well.

It appears to me that the lighting is coming from slightly above and to the left. You can tell this by the fact that the shadows from the model's chin and visible arm are falling below and to the right of the face and arm. I'm not an expert at lighting, so I'm not sure about this, but the lack of harsh shadows on the back of the subject's head might indicate some bounce light, or perhaps a fill light? I don't see overlapping shadows, so maybe I'm wrong about that and the light is a little more centered than I thought. (Notice how in the Vermeer painting the subject's shoulder is pretty dark.)

You can learn a lot by studying classic works by visual artists from a variety of different fields including painting, film photography, cinema, and even animation. Many of the decisions made by these artists have similar reasons for being made, and have similar outcomes. Vermeer didn't have studio lights, but he obviously knew that style of lighting illuminated his subjects in a flattering way. The same is true today!

Comment: This is a great observation and I'm voting it up, but don't be surprised if the original poster comes back and says that they just meant the black background, or indeed just "black and white".